# How do I install NetDrive from a Linux command line (terminal)?

Tags: linux

I want to use NetDrive to mount as local drive storage of my dropbox/google drive account.
I wish to understand what commands do I need to install it from a terminal.

They use Ubuntu 16 as requirement
https://www.netdrive.net/download/?os=linux

Comment: If NetDrive does not work for you, try an alternative, e.g. RClone, https://alternativeto.net/software/rclone/

Comment: I don't want sync files located online locally (I don't want that online files are downloaded on my pc). RClone is good for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install NetDrive you should have `curl` or `wget`
for this answer we are going to go with `wget`

Also, other things we are going to install to get NetDrive to work is the following:

- [Git](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [GCC](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

To begin with, run the follow command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Once you have done that you need to install `git`

Firstly you need to update your local packages, run in terminal this command:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then run the installation command for `git`

```
sudo apt install git
```

Now for GCC

Again update your local packages with:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install GCC

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

After all of this now it's time to install NetDrive
via `wget`
Run the following command on your terminal and that would be it

```
bash -c "$(wget -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetDrive/installer/master/install.sh)"
```

Source: [Install NetDrive for Linux](https://github.com/NetDrive/installer)